# When launching world and robot models, initial attempts succeed, but subsequent launches fail

Tags: turtlebot, roslaunch, multi-robot, world

The first one or two launches of this launch file work without issues, but subsequent launches fail. I am generating two robots in a world, specifically a ridgeback and a turtlebot3 waffle. I suspect (though I'm not certain) that the ridgeback is generated successfully, but when generating the turtlebot3, it shows an error `malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)` and then `Aborted (core dumped)`. Below is some information about launching this file. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

My ROS version is Noetic, and the Gazebo version is 'Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 11.11.0'

```
auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [60228]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 8c951a46-a3fd-11ee-894c-23269562b066
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [60240]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [60247]
process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [60251]
process[robot0/robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [60256]
process[robot0/controller_spawner-5]: started with pid [60258]
process[robot0/ekf_localization-6]: started with pid [60259]
process[robot0/twist_mux-7]: started with pid [60260]
process[robot0/urdf_spawner-8]: started with pid [60262]
process[robot1/robot_state_publisher-9]: started with pid [60271]
process[robot1/spawn_urdf-10]: started with pid [60277]
[INFO] [1703601988.619696, 0.000000]: Waiting for /clock to be available...
[INFO] [1703601988.621064, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter robot_description
[INFO] [1703601988.624059, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ INFO] [1703601988.658389609]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1703601988.658966065]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1703601988.688605701]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1703601988.689235530]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1703601989.006075763]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1703601989.014396738]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ WARN] [1703601989.194141144, 345.281000000]: Failed to meet update rate! Took 345.28100000000000591
[ WARN] [1703601989.195132006, 345.281000000]: Failed to meet update rate! Took 345.2610000000000241
[INFO] [1703601989.225986, 345.313000]: /clock is published. Proceeding to load the controller(s).
[INFO] [1703601989.229840, 345.317000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[INFO] [1703601989.232343, 345.319000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ WARN] [1703601989.275333503, 345.348000000]: Failed to meet update rate! Took 0.045000000000000005274
[INFO] [1703601989.522553, 345.448000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
[ INFO] [1703601989.528201631, 345.448000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/robot0/'
[ INFO] [1703601989.528245057, 345.448000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /robot0/)
[ INFO] [1703601989.528692674, 345.448000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = /robot0/)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1703601989.647281963, 345.448000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1703601989.647340243, 345.448000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: robot0
[ INFO] [1703601989.647597049, 345.448000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [/robot0/robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ INFO] [1703601989.778983069, 345.448000000]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
[ INFO] [1703601989.782855249, 345.448000000]: ForceBasedMove using gains: yaw: 500 x: 10000 y: 10000

[ INFO] [1703601989.782875400, 345.448000000]: robotBaseFrame for force based move plugin: robot0/base_link

[ INFO] [1703601989.801795893, 345.448000000]: GazeboRosJointStatePublisher is going to publish joint: front_rocker
[ INFO] [1703601989.801818717, 345.448000000]: Starting GazeboRosJointStatePublisher Plugin (ns = /robot0/)!, parent name: robot0
[INFO] [1703601989.834937, 345.479000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1703601989.836317, 345.481000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1703601989.837464, 345.482000]: Loading controller: ridgeback_joint_publisher
[INFO] [1703601989.841833, 345.487000]: Loading controller: ridgeback_velocity_controller
[ INFO] [1703601989.845589718, 345.491000000]: Use the roller's radius rather than the wheel's: 0.
[ INFO] [1703601989.845842093, 345.491000000]: Front left wheel joint (wheel0) is : front_left_wheel
[ INFO] [1703601989.846134860, 345.491000000]: Back left wheel joint (wheel1) is : rear_left_wheel
[ INFO] [1703601989.846334802, 345.491000000]: Back right wheel joint (wheel2) is : rear_right_wheel
[ INFO] [1703601989.846615346, 345.492000000]: Front right wheel joint (wheel3) is : front_right_wheel
[ INFO] [1703601989.846840386, 345.492000000]: Controller state will be published at 50Hz.
[ INFO] [1703601989.847130821, 345.492000000]: Velocity commands will be considered old if they are older than 0.25s.
[ INFO] [1703601989.847236256, 345.492000000]: Base frame_id set to base_link
[ INFO] [1703601989.847338762, 345.492000000]: Odom frame_id set to odom
[ INFO] [1703601989.847565709, 345.493000000]: Publishing to tf is disabled
[ INFO] [1703601989.852574699, 345.496000000]: Wheel seperation in X: 0.638
[ INFO] [1703601989.852599247, 345.496000000]: Wheel seperation in Y: 0.551
[ INFO] [1703601989.852660184, 345.496000000]: Wheel radius: 0.0759
[INFO] [1703601989.855135, 345.499000]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: ridgeback_joint_publisher, ridgeback_velocity_controller
[INFO] [1703601989.857846, 345.502000]: Started controllers: ridgeback_joint_publisher, ridgeback_velocity_controller
[robot0/urdf_spawner-8] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/ne/.ros/log/8c951a46-a3fd-11ee-894c-23269562b066/robot0-urdf_spawner-8*.log
[ INFO] [1703601990.360493941, 345.650000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: 'robot1'
[ INFO] [1703601990.364321557, 345.650000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = robot1)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1703601990.517117100, 345.650000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: 'robot1'
[ INFO] [1703601990.517231789, 345.650000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = robot1)
[ INFO] [1703601990.517756966, 345.650000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = robot1)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1703601990.525351604, 345.650000000]: Starting plugin DiffDrive(ns = robot1/)
[ INFO] [1703601990.525398087, 345.650000000]: DiffDrive(ns = robot1/): <rosDebugLevel> = na
[ INFO] [1703601990.525661081, 345.650000000]: DiffDrive(ns = robot1/): <tf_prefix> = 
[ INFO] [1703601990.526080006, 345.650000000]: DiffDrive(ns = robot1/): Advertise joint_states
[ INFO] [1703601990.526127232, 345.650000000]: DiffDrive(ns = robot1/): Try to subscribe to cmd_vel
[ INFO] [1703601990.526826192, 345.650000000]: DiffDrive(ns = robot1/): Subscribe to cmd_vel
[ INFO] [1703601990.527012105, 345.650000000]: DiffDrive(ns = robot1/): Advertise odom on odom 
**malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)**
[robot1/spawn_urdf-10] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/ne/.ros/log/8c951a46-a3fd-11ee-894c-23269562b066/robot1-spawn_urdf-10*.log
**Aborted (core dumped)**
**[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 60247, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/ne/MAPF/ROS/myMap/obstacle_world.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/ne/.ros/log/8c951a46-a3fd-11ee-894c-23269562b066/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/ne/.ros/log/8c951a46-a3fd-11ee-894c-23269562b066/gazebo-2*.log**
```